# Magento product name as text instead of varchar

Tags: magento

How could I alter the product name attribute so it's text instead of varchar? Is there a way of doing this through Magento?

I'm currently migrating an old database and the product names are much longer than varchar can fit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Magento expert yet, but out of a common knowledge of E-Commerce systems, I'm not sure this is a good idea. The product name is being used in numerous places around the system (e.g. in reports; in confirmation E-Mails ....) that would all have to be checked for limitations and breaking layouts.

Would it not be conceivable to either

- Put the long name into a description field that already is of the type `TEXT`, and put a cut-off version into the name field
- Put the long name into a description field, and alter any needed layouts so that description field is shown in place of the product name?

Comment: Agreed. It's theoretically possible, but almost certainly a bad idea. The second field idea should hopefully cover you. Also, keep in mind that having an extremely long product name is probably disruptive to purchasing for customers.